# Run a simple Java program in the OpenShift cloud

Tags: java, rmi, openshift

what is the easiest method to run a Java program inside a gear on OpenShift?

I don't need a complex framework or web server. I just need a container to which I can upload my Java Files, compile and execute them in the cloud. The application I have in mind is very simple, a program that gathers some information and that I can connect to via RMI and just ask for the data.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at [this article](https://www.openshift.com/developers/java?sc_cid=70160000000UJC4AAO&gclid=COjVt5zS0b4CFaVQOgodPEwAnA)?

Comment: I did, but I was wondering if there's a simpler way, without having to use an application server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need an application server you'd better take a look at DIY cartridge. You'd just have to create it from your code:

`rhc app-create yourapp diy-0.1 --from-code git://github.com/(...).git`

You could even use git hooks to launch it. Take a look at the hooks I use at my [Wedding Tables Planner web](https://github.com/juanignaciosl/wedding-tables-planner-web), based in [this template](https://github.com/opensas/play2-openshift-quickstart#readme).

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I need! I can't believe I didn't come across this solution earlier, I was making my life difficult with JBossAS7.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, DIY are still "experimental stuff", so they're not as publicized as they could be, and Application Server cartridges seem to be more interesing for many people :)

Answer (score 1):

I think easiest is tu run a jbossas app and stop the jbossas cart if necessary. Otherwise you may play with the diy app type.